# Textbox still validating even when hidden - bassistance plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question where a textbox appears depending on what radio button is chosen. The problem is the validation for that hidden textbox is still responding despite the fact that it is hidden. eg. choosing the `same` option hides the textbox again, or doesn't show it at all because both `higher` and `lower` were not clicked yet. Any ideas? I tried using the toggle operation.

Here is the validation plugin code:

```
$("#manufacturingForm").validate({
        rules: {
            percentRevenue: {
                required: true,
                range: [0, 100]
            },
            revenueHigher: {
                required: true,
                range: [0, 100]
            },
            revenueLower: {
                required: true,
                range: [0, 100]
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
// Revenue
    $("input[name='comp-revenues']").on('change', function() {
        var revenue = $(this).val();
        var opposite = '';

        if(revenue == 'Higher') { 
            opposite = 'Lower'; 
            $("#revenuePercent" + opposite).hide();
            $("#revenuePercent" + revenue).show();
        }
        else if (revenue == 'Lower') { 
            opposite = 'Higher';
            $("#revenuePercent" + opposite).hide();
            $("#revenuePercent" + revenue).show();
        }
        else {
            if ($("#revenuePercentHigher").css('display') == 'inline') {
               $("#revenuePercentHigher").hide();
            } 
            else if ($("#revenuePercentLower").css('display') == 'inline') {
               $("#revenuePercentLower").hide();
            }
            else {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        }
    });
```

And my HTML code:

```
<p class='question'>As compared to the same month last year, was it higher, same or lower?</p>
            <input type='radio' name='comp-revenues' value='Higher' required>Higher<br />
            <input type='radio' name='comp-revenues' value='Same'>Same<br />
            <input type='radio' name='comp-revenues' value='Lower'>Lower<br />

            <span id='revenuePercentHigher' class='percent'>
                <p class='question'>About how many percent higher?</p>
                <input name='revenueHigher' type='text' /><br />
            </span>

            <span id='revenuePercentLower' class='percent'>
                <p class='question'>About how many percent lower?</p>
                <input name='revenueLower' type='text' /><br />
            </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Jquery `on()` function with event delegation to dynamically add/remove text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick thought: try disabling the input field as well, not just hiding it. Like so:

```
$("#revenuePercent" + opposite).hide().prop('disabled', true);
$("#revenuePercent" + revenue).show().prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically hiding the span's that act as a wrapper for your input tags. It will not prevent validation checks.
Rather, you try and disable those input boxes on change event.

Replace your code with

```
        if(revenue == 'Higher') { 
            opposite = 'Lower'; 
            $("#revenuePercent" + opposite).hide();
            $("#revenuePercent" + opposite +" input").attr('disabled','disabled');
            $("#revenuePercent" + revenue).show();
            $("#revenuePercent" + revenue +" input").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else if (revenue == 'Lower') { 
            opposite = 'Higher';
            $("#revenuePercent" + opposite).hide();
            $("#revenuePercent" + opposite +" input").attr('disabled','disabled');;
            $("#revenuePercent" + revenue).show();
            $("#revenuePercent" + revenue + " input").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
```

Hope this works for your validation checks.

You can also disable and hide (any or both  text box depending upon prior selection of radio button)  on document load or document ready action that will give you a  good UI ..............
Try these on document ready if necessary

```
$('#revenuePercentHigher input , #revenuePercentLower input ').attr('disabled','disabled');
 $('#revenuePercentHigher  , #revenuePercentLower  ').hide();
```